# get several substrings back as an array from one string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I have this string:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
          <a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C target="_blank">
            <h4>C</h4>
          </a>
          <p>C or c is the third letter in the English alphabet and a letter of the alphabets of many other writing systems which inherited it from the Latin alphabet.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement target="_blank">
            <h4>Copyright infringement</h4>
          </a>
          <p>Copyright infringement (colloquially referred to as piracy) is the use of works protected by copyright law without permission for a usage where such permission is required, thereby infringing certain exclusive rights granted to the copyright holder, such as the right to reproduce, distribute, display or perform the protected work, or to make derivative works.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_the_United_States target="_blank">
            <h4>Copyright law of the United States</h4>
          </a>
          <p>The copyright law of the United States is intended to encourage the creation of art and culture by rewarding authors and artists with a set of exclusive rights.</p>
        </li>
```

I want to replace all of the substrings between 'href="' and and the next space ' '.
The goal is to change the link for another one.

The function I use is:

```
const findSubstrings = function (json: string) {
    const subStrings = json.substring(
        json.indexOf("href=") + 1, 
        json.indexOf(" ")
    );
}
```

The problem is that it only returns one value, I want to get all the links back as string in an array. I guess I could split the big string into smaller substrings and than into smaller substrings, but feels like overkill. Is there a easier way to go about it?

Comment: What environment are you running this in? A browser? What do you want to change the links to?

Comment: I'm running it in react. Doing npm start.

I want to change it to the wikipedia:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=opensearch&search=`


This is so that I can get the HTML from the API call and then use a dark mode bootstrap. In short it's a personal project to create a darkmode wiki page.

The project can be seen here: 
https://github.com/cnohall/TypeScript-React-DarkWiki

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. You should parse this markup and modify the `href` attributes using DOM traversal methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/href=\S+/g, (oldLink) => {
    console.log(oldLink);
    const newLink = "https://www";
    return "href=" + newLink;
});
```